# Python Typer and multiple inputs to CLI option

Tags: python, typer

I'm trying to use Python Typer to create a CLI with an option input that:

- takes multiple values
- is of a List type.

For example:

```
$ ./my_cli --device 1 2
...
Got unexpected extra argument (2)
```

My code looks like this:

```
def main(
    devices: List[str] = typer.Option([], help="Devices to query"),
):
    print(f"CLI option is {devices}")
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```py
from typing import List, Optional

import typer


def main(device: Optional[List[str]] = typer.Option(None)):
    if not device:
        print("No provided devices")
        raise typer.Abort()
    for d in device:
        print(f"Processing device: {d}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    typer.run(main)
```

And then it can be used like in:

```bash
$ ./my_cli --device 1 --device 2
```

Take a look at [the documentation](https://typer.tiangolo.com/tutorial/multiple-values/multiple-options/).

If the only input for the CLI is a list of devices, you can simplify it to using [arguments](https://typer.tiangolo.com/tutorial/multiple-values/arguments-with-multiple-values/) instead. Then it could be used like:

```bash
$ ./my_cli 1 2
```

Comment: ok. But i was thinking you could supply the various devices just using a single `--device`.

Comment: You can supply multiple values to an option only when there is a fixed number of values. See [here](https://typer.tiangolo.com/tutorial/multiple-values/options-with-multiple-values/). "You can set the number of values and types to anything you want, but it has to be a fixed number of values."

Comment: I had a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76555213/how-do-i-pass-all-arguments-in-typer-to-a-command/76555214).

Answer (score -1):

```
from pathlib import Path
from typing import List

import typer


def main(files: List[Path], celebration: str):
    for path in files:
        if path.is_file():
            print(f"This file exists: {path.name}")
            print(celebration)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    typer.run(main)
```

Comment: code-only answers are not so useful, please provide more details