# How do I pass all arguments in typer to a command?

Tags: python, typer

I have a complex CLI with a number of commands, each of which uses a `Typer` instance as described in [the docs](https://typer.tiangolo.com/tutorial/subcommands/add-typer/). One of those commands runs another external command which has its own arguments, but also has a default behaviour if no arguments are passed. I would like to pass all arguments to that command without trying to define them explicitly in my code.

My code looks something like this, using `banana` as the external subcommand I want to run. In `mycli.py`:

```py
app = typer.Typer()
app.add_typer(banana.app, name="banana", help="Run the banana command")
```

then in `banana.py` I want something like this:

```py
app = typer.Typer()

def default(<with an optional list of arguments>):
   # TODO run the banana command with all arguments passed to it
   #   or nothing if no arguments were passed
```

More specifically, the command I am trying to run is inside a Docker image.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through many iterations before I figured it out. In `banana.py`:

```py
from typing import List, Optional
import docker
import typer
from typing_extensions import Annotated

@app.callback(invoke_without_command=True)
def main(commands: Annotated[Optional[List[str]], typer.Argument()] = None) -> None:
    # run the banana command with all arguments
    client = docker.from_env()
    client.containers.run(image, commands)
```

The above code (fully typed!) means I can run commands like the following:

```bash
mycli banana
mycli banana arg1
mycli banana arg1 arg2 arg3
```

and it all works as expected!

Suggestions for improvement would be greatly appreciated.

NB. This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74703722/python-typer-and-multiple-inputs-to-cli-option) but is not quite the same. And [this issue](https://github.com/tiangolo/typer/issues/18) was helpful too.